# how to disable Hardware prefetcher in core i3/i7

Tags: linux, cpu, bios

Is there any way to disable the hardware prefetcher in Intel core i3 /i7 ?

Although I have posted related question in stackoverflow, but no solution till now.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474791/does-intel-support-disabling-hardware-prefetcher-through-msr-for-core-i7

I have tried to change the MSR bit , but got error message. I have mentioned it  here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435788/unable-to-disable-hardware-prefetcher-in-core-i7

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I just got to know from the [link](http://arbidprobramming.blogspot.in/2012/11/disable-hardware-prefetching-in-intel.html), that from Nehalem onwards, Intel has disabled the option of controlling  prefetching from the MSRs, the BIOS seems to be the only way then. I'm not sure how prefetching can be disabled if the BIOS does not provide an option.